# How to annotate the return value of a function, where the value is based on a call to its input parameter?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

In the code below there is a `BaseService` and `BaseConfig` which relate to each other and can both be inherited from. For example, a `ConcreateService` will make use of a `ConcreteConfig`.
This is all fine and works as expected. After calling `ConcreateService.get_config_type()` I do indeed receive a `ConcreteConfig` which both mypy and my IDE recognizes correctly.

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Type


class BaseConfig: pass
class ConcreteConfig(BaseConfig): pass

C = TypeVar("C", bound=BaseConfig)
class BaseService(Generic[C]):
    CONF: Type[C]
    @classmethod
    def get_config_type(cls) -> Type[C]:
        return cls.CONF

class ConcreteService(BaseService[ConcreteConfig]):
    CONF = ConcreteConfig

conf = ConcreteService.get_config_type()
reveal_type(conf)  # Revealed type is "Type[mypy.ConcreteConfig]"
```

The problem I'm facing is that I now need to have a function that return the `ConcreteConfig` but doing this based on only the type of service.

```
T = TypeVar("T", bound=BaseService, covariant=True)
def get_concrete_config(service: Type[T]) -> ?????:  # What do I put here as return type?
    return service.get_config_type()
```

Because `service` isn't available yet when annotating the function, I can't use it to read the return type.
I also can't specify the `BaseConfig` as I then wouldn't be able to see any methods defined specifically in the `ConcreteConfig`.
There are many services and configuration classes and keeping track of which service uses which config is quite difficult, which is why I'd like to only pass in the service type and from there read/infer the config type (as it's always defined in the `CONF` attribute).

What do I put as return type to `get_concrete_config()` function?

Comment: Note that you cannot enforce `CONF` to be of the right type. If you could , you should have used `CONF: ClassVar[Type[C]]` but mypy does not support typevar in ClassVar.
All in all, it feels like there's a better design lurking here, from the perspective of the type system.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for the new TypeVar:

```
def get_concrete_config(service: Type[BaseService[C]]) -> Type[C]:
    return service.get_config_type()
```